# Cant get the private ip from an EC2 result

Tags: ansible

Trying to create a playbook that will let me choose if i want spot or On-demand EC2 with passing external var, all going fine except the part of getting the private ip from the result and settings it as fact for further usage.

i've tried different paths like item.instances[0].private_ip
and just cant seems to get the right one.

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: when true
    ec2:
      region: us-east-1
      instance_type: t2.nano
      key_name: test_key
      instance_type: t2.micro
      image: ami-0aec0138b2*****
      wait: yes
      count: 1
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-00fdda1452d****
      assign_public_ip: no
      spot_price: 1
    register: ci_ec2_true
    when: var == "true"


  - name: when false
    ec2:
      region: us-east-1
      instance_type: t2.nano
      key_name: test_key
      instance_type: t2.micro
      image: ami-0aec0138b2****
      wait: yes
      count: 1
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-00fdda1452d0****
      assign_public_ip: no
    register: ci_ec2_false
    when: var == "false"



  - name: ci_ec2_true
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ci_ec2_true }}"

  - name: Spot / On-demand var router
    set_fact:
      ci_ec2: "{{ ci_ec2_true if ci_ec2_false is skipped else ci_ec2_false }}"


  - name: debug ci_ec2
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ci_ec2 }}"

  - name: ec2_prov - set fact for all ci_machine_ips
    set_fact: private_ips="{{ item.instances[0].private_ip }}"
    with_items: "{{ ci_ec2 }}"
    register: ci_ec2_ip_results

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ci_ec2_ip_results }}"
```

The expected result should be the private ip value, instead im getting this error:

```
TASK [ec2_prov - set fact for all ci_machine_ips] ******************************
**********
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'instances'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/test/when-create.yml': line 50, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: ec2_prov - set fact for all ci_machine_ips\n    ^ here\n"}
```

the command used to run the playbook is:

```
ansible-playbook when-create.yml -e var=true
```

```
TASK [debug ci_ec2] ************************************************************

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "instance_ids": [
            "i-0485794cd8a299b27"
        ],
        "instances": [
            {
                "ami_launch_index": "0",
                "architecture": "x86_64",
                "block_device_mapping": {
                    "/dev/xvda": {
                        "delete_on_termination": true,
                        "status": "attached",
                        "volume_id": "vol-0cd42f8696aef9bbd"
                    }
                },
                "dns_name": "",
                "ebs_optimized": false,
                "groups": {
                    "sg-07c7177c": "default"
                },
                "hypervisor": "xen",
                "id": "i-0485794cd8a299b27",
                "image_id": "ami-0aec0138b2a5****",
                "instance_type": "t2.micro",
                "kernel": null,
                "key_name": "test_Key",
                "launch_time": "2019-05-11T16:41:10.000Z",
                "placement": "us-east-1a",
                "private_dns_name": "ip-10-220-129-224.ec2.internal",
                "private_ip": "10.220.129.224",
                "public_dns_name": "",
                "public_ip": null,
                "ramdisk": null,
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "root_device_name": "/dev/xvda",
                "root_device_type": "ebs",
                "state": "running",
                "state_code": 16,
                "tags": {
                    "Created_By": "InstanceLaunch"
                },
                "tenancy": "default",
                "virtualization_type": "hvm"
            }
        ],
        "tagged_instances": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so eventually i found the way...

```
- name: ec2_prov - set fact for all ci_machine_ips
  set_fact: private_ips="{{ item.private_ip }}"
  with_items: "{{ ci_ec2.instances }}"
  register: ci_ec2_ip_results
```